# Relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, relationship

I have such structure of tables:

```
posts
    id - integer
    name - string

videos
    id - integer
    name - string

tags
    id - integer
    name - string

taggables
    tag_id - integer
    taggable_id - integer
    taggable_type - string
```

And i have have Many To Many Polymorphic Relations.
How from updating post I can update list of tags of this post?

Comment: Did you try with `attach()` just like a Many To Many relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Detach all tags from the post, then attach new tags:

  ```
  $tag_ids = [1, 2, 3...];
  $post->tags()->detach();
  $post->tags()->attach($tag_ids);
  ```
- Or detach tag ids no longer needed from the post, then attach new tags:

  ```
  $tag_ids_for_detach = [4, 5, 6...];
  $tag_ids_for_attach = [1, 2, 3...];
  $post->tags()->detach($tag_ids_for_detach);
  $post->tags()->attach($tag_ids_for_attach);
  ```

Comment: Can you wite more expanded answer?